# TFDQuery.Append lento

Tags: delphi, firedac

Append lento.
TFDQuery ao aplicar valor em um field com SGDB na nuvem, consome 144 milésimos de segundos, alterando a property TFDQuery.AutoCalcFields para false, esse tempo chega a 071 milésimos de segundos. Usando o SGDB na rede local, o tempo fica 004 milésimos de segundos.
Exemplo:
qry.Append;
qryCODITEM.AsInteger := 1; //Aqui fica lento com o SGDB na nuvem.

Acredito que o firedac vai até o SGDB a cada alteração do field. Aguêm já teve cenário igual? Tem como melhorar?

Comment: E se ao invés de de colocar em `Append` você fizer um `Insert` na `qry`, adicionar o valor ao campo e em seguida um `Post`?

Comment: Alterei de Append para Insert e a performance foi a mesma. O post eu chamo após editar os campos, coloquei o exemplo só até a parte onde fica lento.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido.
Existe o evento OnDataChange vinculado no TDataSource.